# How to select multiple checkbox item from a dropdown button in Cypress

Tags: javascript, typescript, automation, arguments, cypress

Hi folks I am new into cypress

I have a dropdown checkbox button from where I have to select multiple values at once

[image: enter code here]

For this I have created a local function in type script as below

### function calling

```
selectItems('Item 1','Item 4')
```

### function definition

```
selectItems(value1: any, value2: any){
cy.get('dropdownlocator').click();
cy.get('dropdownlocatorCheckboxItems').contains(value1).click();
cy.get('dropdownlocatorCheckboxItems').contains(value2).click()
}
```

This is working fine but what I wanted is instead of doing the hard coding for each value I should make it so generic that if I pass single value in param it will work or if I pass more than 2 values it should also work

Comment: I'm not familiar with cypress, but can you make your arguments for `selectItems()` into an array instead, then loop over that array within the function?

Answer (score 3):

There are two things that you can take a look at:

[The arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

This is a hidden object of every function call, and can be used to figure out what arguments are passed in without defining what is passed in

```js
selectItems() {
  cy.wrap(arguments).each(value => {
    cy.contains('dropdownlocatorCheckboxItems', value).click()
  })
})
...
selectItems(value1)

selectItems(value1, value2)
```

This may cause trouble with the Typescript compiler, it's an older technique pre-typescript.

There is also [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

```js
selectItems(...theValues) {
  for (const value of theValues) {
    cy.contains('dropdownlocatorCheckboxItems', value).click()
  }
})
...
selectItems(value1)

selectItems(value1, value2)
```

---

Changing the parameter type to a string array is naïve.

You only shift the problem to the line before the function call

```js
const selectItems(values: string[]) = {
 ...
})

const values = [value1, value2]  // might as well just put these in the call params
selectItems(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the signature of your function to an array and use `.forEach` to iterate through the array values.

```js
const selectItems(values: string[]) = {
  cy.get('dropdownlocator').click().then(() => {
    // Add the forEach inside a .then to ensure it happens after you click the `dropdownlocator`
    values.forEach((value) => {
      cy.get('dropdownlocatorCheckboxItems').contains(value).click();
    })
  })
}
...
selectItems(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']);
selectItems(['foo']);
```

Comment: I think you have missed out two closing bracket ')' one for the then statement and one for the for each statement can you pls rectify you answer

Comment: Updated! Apologies on that, SO can be difficult to format code in directly :)